# How can this isolated DC/DC converter claim a 3kv rating?

Tags: voltage-regulator, dc-dc-converter, high-voltage, mains, transient

I'm referring to the Murata Power Solutions CME series DC/DC converters.

Datasheet: http://www.murata-ps.com/data/power/ncl/kdc_cme.pdf

If you look at the footprint of package (the -3C variant), there is no way that a pin spacing of 2.54mm is a good clearance/creepage for a 3kv transient. The -DC package variant would be more acceptable, but it is rated for only 1kv. What am I missing?

Comment: You're missing the slot in the PCB and the part of the case that sticks through that slot.

Comment: Yea I originally thought the same thing, but it doesn't look to be the case based this sample photo--- http://sigma.octopart.com/26686083/image/Murata-CME0303S3C.jpg

Any other ideas?

Comment: Well... it would have to be a very *thin* slot...

Comment: But in all seriousness, the *part itself* can be rated for that voltage; getting a layout that would be rated for that voltage is the implementer's problem.

Comment: True, but in this case it would seem very impractical, if not impossible to achieve a proper layout. With a proper slot you can remove creepage concerns, you still have issues with clearance. Every other comparable product has at least 5-6mm between isolated pins.

Comment: If it were up to me I'd either use dead bug construction for this piece or pot it in something else. *If* I needed that much isolation.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Just make an answer so I can upvote you :)

Comment: Fair enough. Even so, this part is meant for PCB mounting, and is also meant to withstand large transients. You defeat the function of the device by placing the isolated input and output so damn close together! And I do indeed need at least 2kv isolation for a mains application.

Comment: I'll be contacting Murata because I truly am curious. It makes absolutely no sense IMO, especially because all other devices in the 3kv isolation range have >6mm gap. If anyone has any other ideas, please chime in!

Comment: Note on page 2 in the datasheet: "The isolation test voltage represents a measure of immunity to transient voltages **and the part should never be used as an element of a safety isolation system**". They're just rating it to survive a transient event, not to protect users, so this should not be what provides isolation from mains in your system.

Comment: so what is an isolated dcdc good for if it can't be used in a "safety isolation system"? I mean, what do we isolate things for if not for safety?

Comment: You can isolate things for functionality. Battery maintenance and supervision in a 300V multi-cell pack for example needs the isolation simply to work. Using this device there would have to be other means to guarantee safety.

Comment: Good find on page2. Thought I had thoroughly read the thing from top to bottom before posting, but evidently not. Thanks photon